# Javascript inheritance - can't access methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I think I'm probably doing something silly, but I'm not sure...

I have these two classes:

```
function Sprite()
{
}

Sprite.prototype.test1 = function()
{
    console.log("test1");
}

function Player()
{
}

Player.prototype.test2 = function()
{
    console.log("test2");
}

Player.prototype = new Sprite();
var player = new Player();

player.test1(); // this works
player.test2(); // this doesn't work..
```

I'm struggling to understand why test2() doesn't work, but test1() does work. If I add properties to these classes then I can access properties from both of them, I just can't call methods from the player class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you over-write `Player.prototype.test2` when you assign a whole object to `Player.prototype`. If you defined `test2` after, it would create the method on the new object instead, and both would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
Player.prototype.test2 = function()
{
     console.log("test2");
}

Player.prototype = new Sprite(); // Original Player.prototype gets overwritten here
```

You first modify a property of `Player.prototype`, then you reassign `Player.prototype` to a new object, losing the original prototype of `Player`.

If you reverse the order of those 2 statements, your test will pass.